# RDP Farm - External Connections

Tags: rdp, terminal, farm

We have originally had a TS running simply by RDPing through port 3389 from an external IP.

We now need to replace what we have, and I would like to use a farm as we want to give users a single environment, but load balanced, redundant etc, so a farm seems ideal.

I have been using this guide, http://thewolfblog.com/2014/02/08/deploying-a-2012-2012r2-remote-desktop-services-farm/ to get to where I am now.

Internally, it works as it should apart from cert issues, which I am happy with for now where I am connecting to the RR DNS for the farm, but get cert error due to the host name not matching.

Environment - 4 servers, virtualised, running Server 2012 R2.

RDP-Broker01 - Broker.
RDP-Gateway01 - Gateway and Web Access.
RDP-Host01 - Session Host.
RDP-Host02 - Session Host.

I have forwarded ports 443 to the Gateway, and can login and it shows an icon to connect to the session collection.

It never does. I think I need to do something with port 3389, but I am unsure where to point it.

I have RDPGateway.company.co.uk and TS.company.co.uk pointing to the external IP that is currently forwarded to the gateway/web access server. I am a little confused if I need to have both hosts publically available to. (I may also have seen it trying to connect to .local addresses publically, obviously this wont work)

I have looked at this too, but just get more confused. [Win 2012 RDS farm not accessible for external clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/591187/win-2012-rds-farm-not-accessible-for-external-clients)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Meant to add, I have purchased a SSL cert, which is installed and is being reported OK by the manage certificates section of deployment properties.

Comment: I now have it working.

The issue now is that is flags certificate mismatch when logging in.

It is showing certificate coming from rdp-host01.mycompany.local, when it should be rdp-host01.mycompany.co.uk. This is the same for the rdp-host02. I get two warnings when trying to log on.